# storing and retrieving lists from files

Tags: python, list

I have a very big list of lists. One of my programs does this:

```
power_time_array = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] # In a short form

with open (file_name,'w') as out:
        out.write (str(power_time_array))
```

Now another independent script need to read this list of lists back.

How do I do this?

What I have tried:

```
with open (file_name,'r') as app_trc_file :
    power_trace_of_application.append (app_trc_file.read())
```

Note: `power_trace_application` is a list of list of lists.

This stores it as a list with one element as a huge string.

**How does one efficiently store and retrieve big lists or list of lists from files in python?**

Comment: Use [python pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: not sure how that compares to pickle in terms of speed/memory, but if your lists have 'regular' shape, you can also try converting to numpy array and then use `numpy.save`

Comment: @Deadlock I used pickle and it works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serialize your list to json and deserialize it back. This really doesn't change anything in representation, your list is already valid json:

```
import json 


power_time_array = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] # In a short form

with open (file_name,'w') as out:
    json.dump(power_time_array, out)
```

and then just read it back:

```
with open (file_name,'r') as app_trc_file :
    power_trace_of_application = json.load(app_trc_file)
```

For speed, you can use a json library with C backend (like *ujson*). And this works with custom objects too.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) library to efficiently read and write structured information (in the form of JSON) to a text file.

- To write data on the file, use [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) , and
- To retrieve json data from file, use [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.dump)

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster:

```
from ast import literal_eval


power_time_array = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]


with open(file_name, 'w') as out:
    out.write(repr(power_time_array))


with open(file_name,'r') as app_trc_file:
    power_trace_of_application.append(literal_eval(app_trc_file.read()))
```